# html.twig file not showing changes on live site

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fullcalendar

I am new to Symfony so maybe there is something that I am unaware of.

I have inherited a website that was created in php/symfony and uses the fullcalendar javascript event calendar.

I am trying to change the weekmode (yes I am aware that weekmode is deprecated but the fixedWeekCount doesn't work either) from variable to fixed in the cpanel of the website.

The file contains the modification but nothing changes on the site itself and when I go to inspect the console it is still showing up as variable instead of fixed.

I have cleared the browser cache and checked on multiple computers and browsers.

I have also tested this on a localhost and it works exactly how I need it to.

Is there something special that I need to do to allow the cpanel to display the correct setting on the live site?

Comment: I don't believe it's the user's browser.  Whenever I had to make a change to the non-php portion of Symphony, I had to clear the cache of the server itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you need to refresh the caches.

Accessing it via a terminal, you should do:

```
APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 php bin/console cache:clear
```

***More info***: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#d-clear-your-symfony-cache

If you cannot or do not have any sort of terminal access, possibly you could remove the files located under `var/cache/prod/`